# Best practice fit web layout to one page

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to create a print layout for a web page. It is already design as if it would be one page, but since HTML and CSS is not for print I ran into a problem fitting the "digital" page to a "real printable" page.
I know there a some `@media print and (min-resolution: 72dpi)` options, but I can not predict every printer resolution.

So my question: ***Is there a better way to fit a web page or part of a web page to ONE real printable page***?

EDIT: To clarifiy my concern. I want the web page's content to **always fit on one** page. I know how to setup print styles for html ;) I know that html/css was not developed for this. But I thought there is some kind of solution for this.

One way I thought of is to generate a PDF that holds all the content and then "shrink" the PDF page size to DIN A4 or whatever I want. But that feels kinda bad.

Comment: Why would you need to predict every resolution? And `@media print` do suffice for your needs, you just need to learn how to use it.

Comment: best use percentage or auto width or height if you want to fit it

Comment: @Henrik: I need the dpi becaus the content has to fit on one page. Depending on the printer dpi a pixel has not always the same ratio in inch/mm

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels True. But then you need a fluid layout that uses percent or em values instead of pixels. Then it will work for both. Otherwise you need one for every dpi possible, and that's quite a few...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a separate stylesheet for your layout directed towards printers by adding the media attribute with the value "print" in the stylesheet declaration, as in the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="<?php echo $Root; ?>styles/layout-screen.php" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="<?php echo $Root; ?>styles/layout-print.php" />
```

Then, in the stylesheet, you would give the html element and each of its full-page-sized children a width of "100%", as in the following.

```
#html, #body, #wrapper { width:100%; }
```

Of course, the height would depend on the amount of content you have, assuming you're using floated divs to contain content. Which you probably should be given the experience level I'm perceiving. Note that this will make the page width fit the printed page regardless of the user's printer dpi resolution.

Comment: Sorry about the PHP root variable in there. Excluding that, you have a relative link. I just prefer my links a little more... absolute.

Comment: Yeah I was just addressing that sorry again, don't get your panties in a twist Srivas.. whatever your name is.

Comment: So, to clarify: **<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="styles/layout-print.php" />**

Comment: @Scopace But this won't fit the all the content to one real page. Or am I mistaken? Maybe a short jsfiddle/dabblet example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to write print-only stiles overwriting default styles:

```
@media print {
    /* Your stylesheet for printers here */
}
```

Or you can use a separate stylesheet:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

You don't need to predict any resolution, but remember that printers can override your styles. So, if you need a strict layout (like invoices or any official documents), consider providing PDFs.

I suggest [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) about setting print styles.